# Cannot jump out of the finally block

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm trying to return a value from a function. The function `WcfProvider.MetalsPrices` may throw an exception. I want to avoid it.

```
public IEnumerable<PriceOfMetal> GetPrice(int id, DateTime time)
{
        bool condition = false;
        DateTime timenew = time.AddDays(-1);

        var allPrice = from c in db.PriceOfMetal
                       select c;

        foreach (var i in allPrice)
        {
            if (i.Date.Date == timenew.Date && i.ListOfMetaL_Id==id)
            {
                condition = true;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (condition == false)
            {
                var price = WcfProvider.MetalsPrices(id, time, time).Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(
                        a =>
                            new PriceOfMetal()
                            {
                                Date = a.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                                ListOfMetaL_Id = a.Field<int>("MetalId"),
                                Value = a.Field<System.Double>("Price")
                            })
                    .ToList().Single();

                db.PriceOfMetal.Add(price);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            var all = from c in db.PriceOfMetal select c;
            return all;
        }
```

I want to return the value of the block finally. Is it possible? I get an error.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to decide whether your function should return normally or abnormally if an exception occurs inside.

If abnormally (your caller will see the exception):

```
try {
    // do stuff
    return answer;
}
finally {
    // cleanup stuff
}
```

If normally, you need to handle the exception:

```
try {
    // do stuff
}
catch {
    // recover stuff        
}
// cleanup stuff
return answer;
```

You can never put a `return` statement in a `finally` block, because `finally` runs when there is an uncaught exception, and when your function ends (abnormally) due to uncaught exception, there is no return value.

Comment: "finally runs when there is an uncaught exception" - no, finally runs in any case

Comment: @AlexeiS: It is perfectly true that "`finally` runs when there is an uncaught exception".  It is also true that "`finally` runs when there is not an uncaught exception.", but it was the first case that was important to analyze in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

you may need a pattern like this

```
try
{
   return here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Catch any error
   // re throw if you choose, 
   // or you can return if you choose
   return here
}
finally
{
  // allways do whats here
}
```

You might want to read a couple of the pages around here : [**try-catch-finally (C# Reference)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx)

---

Just to build on this a bit more, Imagine if we could return within a finally block

You could have a nasty piece of code like below, which would be confusing at best

```
try
{
    return 10;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return 20;
}
finally
{
    return 30;
}
```

What would the compiler return?

Comment: @Denis bugger, please update your question with some more details, its not quite obvious what your asking, or what the error is

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this but your question is vague and hard to answer. Your code looks over complicated. Anyway it's holiday time. Maybe below will help you along. No guarantees though.

```
public IEnumerable<PriceOfMetal> GetPrice(int id, DateTime time)
{
    DateTime timenew = time.AddDays(-1);

    var allPrice = from c in db.PriceOfMetal
                   select c;
                   where c.Date.Date == timenew.Date
                   and c.ListOfMetal_Id == id

    if (!allPrice.Any())
    {
        try
        {
            var price = WcfProvider.MetalsPrices(id, time, time).Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(a =>new PriceOfMetal
                        {
                            Date = a.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                            ListOfMetaL_Id = a.Field<int>("MetalId"),
                            Value = a.Field<System.Double>("Price")
                        })
                        .ToList().Single();

            db.PriceOfMetal.Add(price);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Eating exceptions like this is really poor. You should improve the design.
        }
    }
    return db.PriceOfMetal;
}
```